# Partial Fraction Decomposition equating coefficiants

Tags: partial-fractions

$$\frac{x^2 + x + 1}{(2 x + 1) (x^2 + 1)}$$

I'm having issues with coming with up with the coefficients for this....my conclusion is
$1=A+2b \\
1=2c+b \\
1=a+c$

am i on the right track? and I'm a little stumped on how to solve the unknowns.

Comment: So, you have three equations with three unknowns, right?

Comment: The equations are right. There are shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

$$
  \frac{x^{2}+x+1}{(2x+1)(x^{2}+1)}  = \frac{A}{2x+1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^{2}+1}.
$$
Mutliply by $2x+1$ and let $x\rightarrow -1/2$ to obtain
$$
           \frac{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}+1}{\frac{1}{4}+1}=A \implies A=\frac{3}{5}.
$$
Set $x=0$:
$$
    \frac{1}{1}=\frac{A}{1}+\frac{C}{1} \implies 1=A+C \implies C=1-A=\frac{2}{5}.
$$
Multiply by $x$ and let $x\rightarrow\infty$ to obtain
$$
    \frac{1}{2}=\frac{A}{2}+B\implies 1=A+2B\implies B=\frac{C}{2}=\frac{1}{5}.
$$

Comment: Cute! I haven't ever seen that approach to determine the coefficients. +1 for that.